# emClient: error "The specific object was not found in store"

Tags: email, calendar, microsoft-teams

I'll post here a solution for an error I had been struggling for a while.

In emClient, every time I had to create an online meeting (using Teams), I couldn't create it and software raised a generic error "The specific object was not found in store".

My emClient is configured to use several email accounts, all from MS Exchange / Office 365 account.

This error prevents any online meeting, recurring or not, to be saved when Teams should be used.

Answer (score 0):

In the menu, go to "Configurations" > "Online Meetings" > "General".

Make sure you add every account as a Microsoft Teams provider. You'll have to log in each one with your browser.

If you add just one provider, from one account, any other account will raise an error trying to save an online meeting in its calendar, probably because it'll try to use that one provider in another account's calendar. You must add each one.